# Shall i learn Assembly Language or C, to Understand how "real programming" works?

Tags: c, assembly, computer-science, theory, low-level

I'm a web developer mostly working in Ruby and C#..

I wanna learn a low level language so i dont look like an ass infront of my (computer science expert) boss.

Ive heard a lot of purist buzz about how assembly language is the only way to learn how computers actually work, but on the other hand C would probably be more useful as a language rather than just for theory.

So my question is..

**Would Learning C teach me enough computer science theory / low level programming to not look like a common dandy (complete tool)?**

Thanks!

Daniel

---

Thanks guys!

Some really great answers,

I think i'll learn C just to get a grasp of memory management, but i think your right and i'll be better off studying more of the languages i use!

Comment: "Computer science" and "how computers work" are two very different beasts.

Comment: This is not the first time I am encountering these questions:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/296/should-i-learn-c
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105190/should-i-learn-assembly-programming

Comment: I suggest you program in machine code as *Real* Programmers write in machine code using binary without the aid of compilers, linkers nor assemblers.  *Real* Programmers are not concerned about productivity but how to best exploit the features of the machine using the least amount of instructions! ;-)

Comment: As far as impressing your boss, just finish the tasks before the deadline and make sure they are robust and correct (produce correct results) and documented so you don't have to be consulted for past works.

Comment: @Thomas Matthews Good shout! I'd rather be a reliable developer than a purist nerd any day!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First learn the actual theory. Learning C's syntax means nothing if you can't do anything meaningful with it. After you have a solid grasp of how algorithms and data structures work, this knowledge will be appliable in most languages you'll probably use.

If you're planning to work in C# and Ruby, I don't see the point in learning assembler just for the sake of doing so.

You'll be fine learning just C since it's C.

You can do "real programming" in any language, as long as you do it right.

Comment: +1 for mentioning algorithms and data structures as the common ground here. I recommend the OP hit a book on that subject before going into memory management. Especially being that he's working with a gc.

Answer (score 3):

> Would Learning C teach me enough
>   computer science theory / low level
>   programming to not look like a common
>   dandy (complete tool)?

You're using C# which can perform unmanaged pointer manipulation, not too far off what you can achieve in C++ land. For instance, games can be successfully programmed in C#, although most games will be C++.

Assembler is basically moving bits of memory around and sometimes doing a bad job of it too if you don't know what you're doing. C++/C compilers create quite good assembly code underneath, so why would you do it yourself unless you had to write low-level driver software. The only bit of assembler in our 2,000,000 lines of mixed C++/C# code is to detect VMWare.

I don't think in this modern age and given your description of your job there is much call for you to know about how many registers you can use on your processor. By all means learn C++, but as mentioned before, learning syntax is not the same as learning how to apply it.

At a minimum learn and understand patterns ([Gang of four](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/Patterns.aspx)), OO design, understand the implications and benefits of different testing methodologies and the impact of all this on business costs.

Comment: Oh, and don't forget database theory!

Comment: I agree, learning syntax is not at all an implication that you know how to use it and use it well.

Answer (score 2):

Learning C will get you all the information you need and be able to accomplish things in a reasonable time.

I suggest you do a few meaningful projects in C, then one or two in an Assembler dialect, maybe for a Microcontroller or specializing in SSE/MMX.

Answer (score 2):

In the end it all comes down to opcodes, registers, and addressing modes, of which C teaches you absolutely nothing.  However, assemblers are tightly coupled to their platforms;  learning how to write assembler on x86 won't help you much when you work on a Sparc or PA-RISC box.

C really isn't going to teach you much that other languages won't in terms of theory.  The thing about C is that it doesn't provide many tools or abstractions beyond naked pointers and byte streams.  You have to roll all your own containers (lists, stacks, queues, etc.), and if you want them to be generic, you have to figure out how to separate the code that needs to be type aware (assignments and comparisons) from the general algorithm.  You have to manage your own memory.  Text processing is a pain in the ass (C doesn't even provide a dedicated string type).

Is that something that would be useful to know for your day-to-day work, or to impress your boss?  Maybe.  I'm not sure how you would *apply* that knowledge in your C# or Ruby code, which operates in a virtual machine (as opposed to native binaries generated from C).

You want to impress your boss with Computer Science knowledge, read up on Turing machines and Markov algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think knowledge of Assembler would make you a better Ruby / C# programmer.

You can go as low level as writing to a disk using a magnetized needle, but if your programs aren't working or are insecure, you wouldn't have gained anything by it.

Learning the syntax of a "new" language won't assist you in gaining more knowledge of the depth of programming.

Comment: I don't agree with you. Knowing assembly, at least a bit of it, helps a lot because you're aware of what's going on exactly, even if you've never written a single line of it.

Comment: @BlackBear: *How* does it help?  Where would you apply that knowledge in C# or Ruby code?

Comment: the knowledge you gain with assembly (not assembly itself) helps you to write efficient code. Try Randall Hyde's book "Write Great Code Volume 2"

Answer (score 1):

Real programming is not about a particular low level programming languge. To understand how a computer works it would be not bad to know some CPU instructions and how the hardware processes them.

To become a good programmer it is absolutely not necessary to know how the hardware works, except you want to program hardware.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't worry about looking like a fool in front of that boss if that's the criteria your boss has for not being a fool.

C and Assembler isn't the best languages if you want to learn computer science. As you know Ruby and C# I guess you know some object orientation.

Answer (score 1):

"Real programming" works the same in every language and that's what you should really worry about. That being said, working up something in C is a very useful exercise/

Learning C won't necessarily teach you too much about how computers work, but it is a good access door to that, considering that it is still the language of choice for system programming.

Learning ASM is of course useful as well, but it's probably uncalled for if you want to apply it to your job. It might teach you a few useful concepts though, or at least help you get a better understanding of how CLR works (or in general, how bytecode compilation and bytecode-compiled code do their stuff). Maybe you could try learning ASM for an older/simpler platform; there's still a heavy Atari 2600 scene around, and due to the platform's inherent limitations, some of the hacks they do to squeeze some extra functions in a game are quite awesome. The modern x86_64 architecture is pretty complex and somewhat hairy, although that's more of a personal opinion than an actual fact. Learning to use a microcontroller might also get the job done, but be warned that many (most?) use a Harvard architecture (i.e. separate program and data memory) which is different from that of a typical general-purpose CPU.

Answer (score 1):

ask your boss first, than do exactly what he tells you, finally ask again for feedback and review of the exercises you will do. act accordingly. repeat until he says "you now know more than me".
this is the more efficient way of exploiting the expertise of a real expert you have the luck to have, and will leave extremely positive impression forever.
it will be as difficult as learning C or assembler alone in your spare time.

Answer (score 1):

> > I wanna learn a low level language so i dont look like an ass infront of my (computer science expert) boss.

This is like so true in many aspects, I learned c++, and haskell for similar reasons, I have no regrets since they taught me many things, but I do understand the peer pressure.

This is a 6 years old question, and it is interesting to see that no one mentioned a good textbook on programming that covers the fundamentals of computer science.

If you want to learn "real programming", just try to tackle 
"Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs"
by MIT Press in your free time. It should cover most if not all of your curiosity with respect to programming whatever your level is.

There is also "The Art of Computer Programming" by Donald Knuth. Knuth is especially well versed in machine languages and other low level stuff.

---

Beware though both of these works are very dense.

Here is my two cents on how to approach them. First of all, they are not "tutorials" that sugar coat your way towards a skill, they introduce a scientific discipline in an appropriate manner, so the mind set of "what am I going to do with this? How can I use this ?" should be replaced by "how does this work ? What does this do ? Why does it do it this way ?".

Try to do the exercises included in the books, but don't push yourself too hard. If you can't do it, it is okay, pass to the next one. 
However if you are not doing any of the exercises given in a section, you should take your time with the chapter, and revise it so that you can at least do couple of the exercises included for the section.

Just keep this up, and you would caught up with your boss/peer in no time. Some chapters/exercises might even be a subject of conversation if you feel like it. He might even like the fact that you are acquiring new skills, or not, don't take my word for it, I do programming not to deal with people.

Answer (score 0):

Well, "Real Programming" doesn't refer to a specific language, or low level languages. In my mind, "real Programming" is the process of analyzing a task, deciding the best way to solve it, and putting that method into a set of simple steps, and then revising and editing as necessary until you have achieved your goal. From that, the language doesn't really matter, it's all in the thought process. Furthermore, there is nothing wrong with high level languages, I use python all the time and love it. However, learning low level languages can really help develop your understanding programs and computers in general. would suggest c, because it is where c# and c++ stem from, and would provide a bases for understanding both those languages.